# How to manage tinymce language packs with composer

Tags: composer-php, tinymce

How to manage tinymce language packs with composer?

They are downloaded separately via https://www.tinymce.com/download/language-packages/.

But if i add it into the composer folder it get overwritten via composer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add them separately to `composer`; there are [language packs on github](https://github.com/tweeb/tinymce-i18n), which are [usable by composer](https://packagist.org/packages/tinymce/?query=tinymce%20i18n):

```
composer require tweeb/tinymce-i18n
```

In `tinymce` you would use it then like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    language: 'de',
    language_url: '/vendor/tweeb/tinymce-i18n/langs/de.js'
});
```